# Can Firewire 800 network interfaces be bonded?

Tags: network, performance, firewire

I've got a few 2009 and 2010 Mac Pros and realized that the Firewire 800 ports are just sitting there going to waste.  I currently use 2 bonded ethernet ports on an additional card to facilitate some faster speeds between two of my workstations that need faster data transfer, but 2 Firewire 800 ports bonded with networking enabled [could proffer several times more performance increase](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/usb-2-0-vs-usb-3-0-vs-esata-vs-thunderbolt-vs-firewire-vs-ethernet-speed/).

Can FW800 with networking enabled be bonded like a standard network interface in macOS 10.13?

Answer (score 1):

So decided to test this with an extra workstation. I was able to assign static IP addresses to both FireWire ports (the first port was active right off the bat, but I had to add the 2nd one).  Both ports can talk in each direction to each workstation on the local isolated subnet.  But when I go to create a bond, the interfaces are not listed when I go into "Manage Virtual Interfaces."  "New Link Aggregate" only shows ethernet devices - NO FIREWIRE devices.

*One thing that I did find out was that 1 FireWire 800 network interface is slightly faster than 2 1 gigabit interfaces bonded.  I was seeing about a +15 MBps down & +3 MBps up differential pretty consistently*

The next thing I need to [try to figure out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329840/how-to-create-link-aggregates-bonded-interfaces-in-shell) is whether or not there's a way to force an aggregate bond from the shell in Terminal.

*UPDATE: So I think I'm close to solving this, but I'm now having a problem where my FW800 ports have stopped functioning on one system and I have a bug report in to Apple right now in hopes to resolve it.  As per my above link, I now think I can perform this on the shell (`sudo networkSetup createBond bond0 interface1 interface2`)... IF it allows me to, but I can't test until I resolve this other issue.*