# How to create link aggregates (bonded interfaces) in shell?

Tags: network, command-line

How do you create link aggregates for network interfaces from the shell in Terminal on macOS 10.13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `man networkSetup`.

Execute the following to bond interfaces `en2` & `en3`:

```
sudo networkSetup createBond bond0 en2 en3
```

It is also useful to be able to get all active interfaces (with or without IP, simply labeled as `active` since you might have a primary interface + the interfaces you want to bond):

```
for i in $(ifconfig -lu); do if ifconfig $i | grep -q "status: active" ; then echo $i; fi; done
```